# Generate a PDF document using .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to find a way how to generate a custom PDF document from .NET Standard 2.0. Free or Open-Source library would be of the preference in this case.

I Have already tried PDFSharp, but it does not support .NET Standard 2.0 (or am I wrong here?) and several ports of this library, which all claim to be .NET Standard, do not have the System.Drawing.Common which is necessary to actually write anything to the document.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how could I generate a PDF with my above-mentioned criteria? It does not really matter if I would have to first write HTML and then convert it to PDF or per se convert excel type to PDF. Anything that could give me a PDF would be great.

Comment: System.Drawing has little if anything to do with generating PDF files. That namespace is used for drawing to the screen. It's often used for image manipulation (even though it's not meant for that).  PDF isn't an image format though

Comment: It should be noted that PDFSharp targets .NET Standard 2.0: https://github.com/Didstopia/PDFSharp/blob/master/Didstopia.PDFSharp/Didstopia.PDFSharp.csproj `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried to use a ported version of PDFSharp that supports netstandard2.0 and use the simple Hello World example from PDFSharp (http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample.ashx), but an error comes up telling me that I can't use System.Drawing from line 29 where Font is being initialized.

Comment: @PeterB that's probably *not* the PDFSharp library the OP is talking about. They're using the name of a different popular package. That's why they don't use the `PDFSharp` name in NuGet by the way.

Comment: @PeterB I could not even make this library port that you are mentioning to work. Let alone, it does not seem to be well supported so I would prefer something else if possible.

Comment: @PaulinhoInso that just means you should use a different library. The page you linked to is *old* - there was no .NET Standard back then. iText is a very popular library in Java and .NET which [has a .NET Standard-compatible version](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). It's *very* powerful but a bit cumbersome. There are addons like [itext7.pdfhtml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/) that can convert an HTML file to PDF

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as far as I understand iText is a paid library, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's open source with a community *and* paid licenses. You can [clone it from Github](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) if you want. Same for [pdfhtml](https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfhtml).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos our app is somewhat commercial, thus would need the license, but of course, if there is a possibility a free library is prefered. That is why the question. Thank you, either way, your comments were really helpful.

Comment: In that case buy the license. Or pay the maintainer *something*. At the very least, read the license text - the Community edition may be enough

Comment: @PaulinhoInso there's *no* free software anyway - all open source projects come with specific OSS licenses. You should already be checking the licenses of any OSS libraries you use